# JavaScript files fail from executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript code:

```
    jQuery("document").ready(function ($) {

    var nav = $('.menu-container');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 650) {
            nav.addClass("f-nav");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("f-nav");
        }
    });

});
```

So, it was working untill today, I did not make any special edits that may interupt it. In my browser console I got a 304 Not Modified; I disabled cache and it changed to 200 OK but the file NEVER executes. What could be the problem?
Link to my website: http://www.gameplay-universe.uphero.com/ the grey menu should be fixed after an amount of pixels is scrolled down.

Comment: have you added jQuery link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It was a CSS issue with `html, body { height: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; }`... So I just re-formatted this into: `html, body { overflow-x: hidden; } body { height: 100%; }`.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery("document")` will select an *element* `<document>`. You want to select the document itself. `jQuery(document)` (see removed quotes).

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. Does "document" represent element's id?

Comment: @PowerUser no, `document` represents the entire DOM tree.

Comment: I meant the jQuery("document") part.

Comment: @PowerUser Oh, no. That selects an element with a tagname "document".

Comment: Edited question. Try the link to my website and see is the menu fixed at the top or not. For me it is not but it may be a bug on my machine.

Comment: @PowerUser No, it's not. Try implementing my solution and see if it changes?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change `function ($)`  to `function()`

The first line could be:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery("document")` searching for `<document></document>` elements. There is no such nodes in your DOM and where is no `ready` events for it. `jQuery(document)` will return jQuery object for `document` and will fire `jQuery` special `ready` event.

Change your code to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
//...
});
```

OR (better)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
//...
});
```